# Read column names with hyphen using read.table in R

Tags: r

My column names have hyphens ("-"). When reading as table, the column names have (".") in place of ("-"). I want to retain the column names as-is.

```
df = read.table("meth_clin_kipan_pathanalysis.txt", header=T, sep="\t", row.names=1)
```

Raw:

| TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A | TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Current output:

| TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A | TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Desired output (same as raw, i.e., as-is):

| TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A | TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `check.names=FALSE` argument of [**`read.table`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/read.table) to preserve original column names that have special characters and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rename_with(~stringr::str_replace_all(., '\\.', '-'), everything())
```